# Google Cloud - Is it possible to check available resources in some location (regions, zones)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

It is very annoying if you try to create some instance in a zone but this location lacks some resources and you get a message "*The zone ... does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  '(resource type:compute)'.*"

Can I in some way (console, gcloud, api) check available resources  in some location before a request of a creation instance?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if there is a way to check availability.

One way to avoid this issue would be using [Reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources).
Then you can make use of [Sustained use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#sustained_use) and [Committed use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#committed_use) discounts.

Comment: This solution isn't desired by me because it generates significant costs especially for GPU.